# MYSQL: I got SUMS of columns, now need to update where values match

Tags: mysql

I have dynamically updated tables. 
Today I have 30 rows but for the example lets use 3.

Table 1:

```
color = blue, revenue_yesterday = 40.00
```

Table 2:

```
product_id = 1, color = blue, price = 20.00  
product_id = 2, color = blue, price = 20.00  
product_id = 3, color = red, price = 15.00
```

---

I'm going to run a daily/weekly crontab to check for yesterday's or last week's revenue.

I need a script that will get the sum of prices from table 2 by group and update the revenue_yesterday in table 1 where color matches from table 2. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update Table1
Set revenue_last_month = 
    (
        Select sum(price) 
        from Table2 
        where Table2.color = Table1.color
    )
```